# How can I find the name of the currently open Excel document using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA in Excel to read a spreadsheet and modify its contents.
I need to save the results with a name that is similar to the original file, but with some alterations.

How can I programmatically find the name of the currently open file using vba?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends, here are two possibilities:

```
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name

For Each wk In Workbooks
    Debug.Print wk.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 8):

`ThisWorkbook.Name` will return the file name.
`ThisWorkbook.FullName` will return the directory structure and the file name.

Comment: While your answer is correct I accepted the other answer only because it is what I used. That's why I upvoted your answer as well. Thanks for the quick response.